# Android Notification click won't open same activity with different intent data

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I'm configuring my notifications to open a new instance of ActivityDetail on click:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityDetail.class);
resultIntent.putExtra("object_id", objectId);
...
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder =TaskStackBuilder.create(getApplicationContext());
stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent);
resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

I build each notifications with a different id, as clicking will populate the ActivityDetail with results unique to the notification.

When I receive two notifications, the first one will open ActivityDetail correctly. Clicking the second notification, however, does nothing (except dismiss it), whether I remain on the ActivityDetail screen or not. Specifying the activity launch mode as "singleTop" makes no difference.

I don't seem to have any problems if there is only one notification displayed at a time, but if there are two, the second one always fails to open a new instance of the ActivityDetail on click. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe look into [onNewIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent))?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is happening because you are sending static request code '0' in 'getPendingIntent' method while obtain pending intent. send a separate value for each notification instead of '0'. it will work.
You need to do like this:

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(SEPARATE_INT_VALUE, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

// Now change value of 'SEPARATE_INT_VALUE'
```